# Разные версии php на ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, madelineproto

Всем добра. Есть такой скрипт:

```
<?php
echo phpversion();
if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
require_once 'madeline.php';

?>
```

Madeline требует PHP 8.2, PHP 8.3+.

`phpversion()` Выводит 7.4.33, однако если пропишу `php -v` выдаст PHP 8.3.2-1+ubuntu20.04.1. Как исправить данный момент, чтоыб работал madeline?

Махинации происходят на ubuntu, apache2

Comment: скорее всего у вас установлены несколько версий PHP. откройте ``/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`` найдите ``LoadModule php7_module`` замените на ``LoadModule php8_module`` и не забудьте перезапустить apache: ``sudo service apache2 restart``